# Django 3 Static files is not a registered tag library

Tags: django, django-3.0

I have updated Django 2 to Django 3.

I am receiving below error.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /api/
'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
rest_framework
static
tz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out, Django 3 has removed the old static tag from templates.

Replace

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

with

```
{% load static %}
```

Ref. [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)